# How to sort a table by two columns in mysql with condition?

Tags: mysql

**Mysql**

```
mysql> select origin_id, destination_id,travel_date,departure_time,available_seats from `schedules` WHERE  travel_date = '2014-08-12' and origin_id = '134' and destination_id = '251'  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') limit 10;

+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
| origin_id | destination_id | travel_date | departure_time | available_seats |
+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 06:00 AM       |              34 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 07:00 AM       |              43 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 07:30 AM       |               0 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 07:30 AM       |              34 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 08:30 AM       |               0 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 08:30 AM       |              29 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 10:15 AM       |              36 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 10:15 AM       |               0 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 10:30 AM       |              29 |
|       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 11:00 AM       |               0 |
+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
10 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

first query : in this query i am giving order by departure_time.
but i want all the records which are having available_seats 0 that should come at the end with order by departure_time only.

**Required output**... ??

```
   +-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
    | origin_id | destination_id | travel_date | departure_time | available_seats |
    +-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 06:00 AM       |              34 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 07:00 AM       |              43 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 07:30 AM       |              34 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 08:30 AM       |              29 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 10:15 AM       |              36 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 10:30 AM       |              29 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 07:30 AM       |               0 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 08:30 AM       |               0 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 10:15 AM       |               0 |
    |       134 |            251 | 2014-08-12  | 11:00 AM       |               0 |
    +-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Is it possible with mysql query. or with other way???

Answer (score 0):

You can first use where and order by statement to sort the departure time of non-zero values of available seats and then can apply union with order by to append the zero columned available seats in increasing order of time. Code can be as follows:

```
select origin_id, destination_id,travel_date,departure_time,available_seats from `schedules` WHERE  travel_date = '2014-08-12' and origin_id = '134' and destination_id = '251'  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') limit 10 and available_seats <> 0

union

select origin_id, destination_id,travel_date,departure_time,available_seats from `schedules` WHERE  travel_date = '2014-08-12' and origin_id = '134' and destination_id = '251'  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') limit 10 where available_seats = 0;
```

In short add where available_seats <>  0 in first part of union,
 then 
after union apply available_seats = 0.

Comment: No Krishna we can give only one order by with union/union all i.e at the end of the query.Ex: query1 union query2 order by column asc; because union will return the result in one table, and on that table we can apply order by.

Comment: Yeah. I got it. Thanks... how do u suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN available_seats=0 THEN '99:99' 
    else STR_TO_DATE(departure_time,'%h:%i%p') END
```

Note that you specified a LIMIT clause, which can produce unexpected results.

Also, sorting on a time with AM/PM will not sort chronologically if you have both AM and PM times.

Comment: The CASE expression evaluates to the constant `99:99` if the available_seats is zero, otherwise it evaluates to your sortkey. This causes the zero-seat rows to sort at the end.  Please read the documentation for mysql